# WiX Burn .NET installer not installing in interactive mode

Tags: wix, installation, burn

I am using Burn to install .NET 4.6 and it works mostly as expected--it installs .NET 4.6 if there no issues preventing it. My chain looks like this.

```
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx46Redist"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id='MyApplicationMsi'/>
    </Chain>
```

However, it is not installing in “interactive” mode.  The .NET installer is not shown, I only see the Burn bootstrapper window.  Which is an issue when the .NET installation fails (such as when the correct windows updates are not present), because the user has to dig through the logs to find out what went wrong.  I don’t see an option to make the PackageGroupRef silent/interactive.  The MSI for my application shows (in non-silent mode) as expected.  How can I get the .NET installer to install interactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy-paste the `ExePackage` from [NetFx462.wxs](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/7c8457fa3802858add8981b92996e19574e762da/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx462.wxs) and remove the`/q` argument from `InstallCommand`